# Creating a stored procedure: setting the character set and collation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, character-encoding

When creating a MySQL stored procedure how does one set the character set and collation? The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) does not provide any examples and to the general syntax is slightly unclear.

```
mysql> show procedure status\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: MslLandingSequence
                Name: DeploySkycrane
                Type: PROCEDURE
             Definer: curiosity@localhost
            Modified: 2012-08-04 00:05:16
             Created: 2011-11-12 00:02:45
       Security_type: DEFINER
             Comment: 
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
```

The last three items should be Unicode. Thanks.

Comment: Not a duplicate question per se, but probably the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375957/illegal-mix-of-collations-in-stored-procedure

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn: Thanks. It is not quite the same problem, but some information in the links from that page are relevant. Thank you.

Comment: Stephen: Pretty unrelated stuff actually.
dotancoh: uhm, got answers :) ?

Comment: I wish that I did have an answer. I don't!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> character_set_client is the session value of the character_set_client
> system variable when the routine was created. collation_connection is
> the session value of the collation_connection system variable when the
> routine was created. Database Collation is the collation of the
> database with which the routine is associated. These columns were
> added in MySQL 5.1.21.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-procedure-status.html

In short, open a mysql command line, type in

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

then drop and reimport the stored procedures. This fixed my problem. I don't even want to think about pre 5.1.21 users. They are fumbling in the dark!

Comment: Thank you! `SET NAMES utf8` does in fact affect `character_set_client` and `collation_connection`, but not `Database Collation`. I suspect that the last one must be set, as the name implies, when creating the database and might not actually be a property of the Stored Procedure itself. Nice find!

Comment: take note: UTF8 does not work. it works for me when I set to lowercase. SET NAMES utf8;

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` worked for me (Wanted to use Smileys)

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to the [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13909). It shows that procedure and its parameters are **not** associated with default character set of the database, but always with Binary String.

So you have to explicitly specify *Character set* attribute for parameters.

Simple recreate procedure might not solve the problem.

Comment: I spent all the night to find out the solution of *«Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9C\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA...' for column 'p_name' at row 1»* error. And only thanks to your question I found that MySQL bug :) So, thank you