# mysql cannot insert bulgarian characters via stored procedure, only via command

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, stored-procedures, utf-8

Ubuntu 12.04, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.22

If I insert via command line, all is ok:

```
insert into LocationState (Value, LocationCountryId) VALUES ('Благоевград / Blagoevgrad', 1);
```

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

If I do it calling a stored procedure from the same shell, I get an error:

```
call addState('Благоевград / Blagoevgrad', 'BG');
```

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB0...' for column 'state' at row 31

All is set to utf8 and this is the sp:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addState`(
   IN state   VARCHAR(128),
   IN country VARCHAR(2)
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO `LocationState` (`Value`, `LocationCountryId`) VALUES 
   (
      state, 
      (SELECT `Id` FROM `LocationCountry` WHERE `ShortValue` = country) 
   );

END
```

I tried also with a SET NAMES 'utf8' in the sp but with no luck.

What else can I do ?

btw: bulgarian as well as russian, etc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920153/creating-a-stored-procedure-setting-the-character-set-and-collation

Comment: thanks but I have already tried that and didn't help

Comment: @marco, now that link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920153/creating-a-stored-procedure-setting-the-character-set-and-collation  gives the answer. Follow it again.